# Angular 2 Tour of Heroes Typescript stuck on loading

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

My Angular 2 Tour of Heroes application is stuck on "Loading..." and angular-cli is not reporting any errors, I'm at the fifth part of the tutorial and I have no idea what the problem is. Here are my files that I think are most important. I hope you can see the problem!
Edit: There's one error in the console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined

*hero-detail.component.ts*

```
import 'rxjs/add/operator/switchMap';
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params }   from '@angular/router';
import { Location }                 from '@angular/common';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-hero-detail',
  templateUrl: 'hero-detail.component.html',
})

export class HeroDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() hero: Hero;

  constructor(
    private heroService: HeroService,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private location: Location
  ) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => this.heroService.getHero(+params['id']))
      .subscribe(hero => this.hero = hero);
  }

  goBack(): void {
    this.location.back();
  }
}
```

*heroes.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-heroes',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  template:`
    <h2>My Heroes</h2>
    <ul class="heroes">
      <li *ngFor="let hero of heroes"
        [class.selected]="hero === selectedHero"
        (click)="onSelect(hero)">
        <span class="badge">{{hero.id}}</span> {{hero.name}}
      </li>
    </ul>
    <my-hero-detail [hero]="selectedHero"></my-hero-detail>
  `
})

export class HeroesComponent implements OnInit {
  selectedHero: Hero;
  heroes: Hero[];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {

  }

  onSelect(hero: Hero): void {
    this.selectedHero = hero;
  }

  getHeroes(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getHeroes();
  }
}
```

*app.module.ts*

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { RouterModule }   from '@angular/router';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes.component';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroDetailComponent,
    HeroesComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {
        path: 'heroes',
        component: HeroesComponent
      },
      {
        path: 'dashboard',
        component: DashboardComponent
      },
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/dashboard',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'detail/:id',
        component: HeroDetailComponent
      }
    ])
  ],
  providers: [
    HeroService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})

export class AppModule {

}
```

*app.component.ts*

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
   <h1>{{title}}</h1>
   <nav>
     <a routerLink="/dashboard">Dashboard</a>
     <a routerLink="/heroes">Heroes</a>
   </nav>
   <a routerLink="/heroes">Heroes</a>
   <router-outlet></router-outlet>
 `
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of Heroes'
}
```

*hero.service.ts*

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HEROES } from './mock-heroes';

@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
  getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return Promise.resolve(HEROES);
  }

  getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {
    return this.getHeroes()
      .then(heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === id));
  }
}
```

*dashboard.component.ts*

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

import { Hero } from './hero';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';


@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'my-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'dashboard.component.html',
})

export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  heroes: Hero[] = [];

  constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.heroService.getHeroes()
      .then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug your code?

Comment: open your console and see what are the errors in it

Comment: Have you opened the browser console and looked for an error?

Comment: If you are running this with angular-cli, you need do things differently. Remove 'moduleId: module.id', do not have templates in the Component definitions etc. Read up on it.

Comment: @Aravind There's one error in the console:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'stack' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem with just changing

```
selector: 'my-app'
```

with

```
selector: 'app-root'
```

in **app.component.ts** file. In the beginning of the tutorial it is suggested to start the project from a git repo, but i generated it with angular cli from cmd. I think this is the cause.

Comment: When using Angular-cli with the Tour of Heroes tutorial, one thing I recommend is that as you generate each component or service, you should use the "dry run" flag.  For example, if I want to add a Footer component that displays what version of Angular the code is using, instead of doing this:


`ng generate component Footer`

I would instead do this:

`ng g c Footer -d`

and examine the output first to see if the names *and* the locations of the new component are what I am expecting. Once I see that everything will be correct, I take off the `-d` flag and run the command normally.